# Increment value by one for each project

Tags: sql, oracle, increment

I want to change value of *Version* column and populate it from '0' to a value that increments per *Project_ID* and ordered by *CreatedDate* . This would be in Oracle and it's for existing rows not auto_increment on insert.

Before

| Project_ID | Version | CreatedDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | Jun-1-2011 |
| 2 | 0 | Jun-1-2011 |
| 1 | 0 | Jun-2-2011 |
| 2 | 0 | Jun-2-2011 |
| 1 | 0 | Jun-3-2011 |
| 2 | 0 | Jun-3-2011 |
| 3 | 0 | Jun-4-2011 |
| 1 | 0 | Jun-4-2011 |

Preferred outcome

| Project_ID | Version | CreatedDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Jun-1-2011 |
| 2 | 1 | June-1-2011 |
| 1 | 2 | Jun-2-2011 |
| 2 | 2 | Jun-2-2011 |
| 1 | 3 | Jun-3-2011 |
| 2 | 3 | Jun-3-2011 |
| 3 | 1 | Jun-4-2011 |
| 1 | 4 | Jun-4-2011 |

Haven't tried anything yet, if i were to do a simple

```
UPDATE table_name SET version = version+1  GROUP BY project_id
```

I don't think it'll work

Comment: What are your tries?

Comment: You should have a column for ordering... How are you going to decide which rows should get higher version?

Comment: I think you could use RANK

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov 150%, that's why I asked for tries. Doesn't seems to be pretty logic with only 2 columns. I still think needs debugs or clarify data

Comment: Correct there's ordering by created_date

Comment: @Marin so update your question ...

Comment: Just did thanks. I think RANK  gets close @LeandroBardelli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use analytic function `row_number()over(partition by Project_ID order by created_date)` for this. Unfortunately you can't use analytic functions in

```
update (select ...,analytic_function()... from t) 
set val=new_val
```

but you can use `merge` statement for this:

```sql
merge into t 
using (
    select rowid rid, row_number()over(partition by Project_ID order by created_date) new_value
    from t
    ) new_t
on (t.rowid = new_t.rid)
when matched then 
update set Version = new_value;
```

DBFiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e778bb0b43e6fcc0ce6961d3a7887cd6

Comment: Thank you I think the fiddle works great. Edit: I was a dummy didn't update the alias.

Answer (score 1):

If there's some column that has unique values then it can be done without row_number.

So under the assumption that there's no primary key, and that there's a Created_Date with unique time values.

> ```
> update yourtable t
> set Version = (
>   select count(*)
>   from yourtable t2
>   where t2.Project_ID = t.Project_ID
>     and t2.Created_Date <= t.Created_Date
> );
> ```

8 rows affected

> 

> ```
> select * from yourtable
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | PROJECT_ID | VERSION | CREATED_DATE
> -: | ---------: | ------: | :-----------
>  1 |          1 |       1 | 18-AUG-21   
>  2 |          2 |       1 | 19-AUG-21   
>  3 |          1 |       2 | 20-AUG-21   
>  4 |          2 |       2 | 21-AUG-21   
>  5 |          1 |       3 | 22-AUG-21   
>  6 |          2 |       3 | 23-AUG-21   
>  7 |          3 |       1 | 24-AUG-21   
>  8 |          1 |       4 | 25-AUG-21
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=09dc7f5fe7db2f85634903d831887f93)*

Comment: Thank you I'll have to check it out!

Comment: If you check out the fiddle then you'll notice it also contains a merge. It'll even work if it only sorts by version. But it will be random then.